# Windows 10 raw usb access for fastboot and adb

Tags: android, windows, windows-10, adb, fastboot

I'm working on [an electron app that wraps fastboot and adb executables](https://github.com/ubports/ubports-installer) to communicate with android devices. It works on Windows 7, Linux, and macOS. On Windows 10, the program can only detect the android device when running from source. When running as an exe package, it does not work. When running the same adb and fastboot binaries the programm is calling from powershell, I can see the device, but the program can't. Running the app as an administrator does not help.

Is there some security feature in Windows 10 blocking raw usb access?